# Android: Loading Large Images with Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, out-of-memory, universal-image-loader

I'm trying to make an activity like the image below. On the imageview with the viewpager I load some random images and also on the smaller ones. When someone clicks on the smalls I update the views with new images. My problem is that when I click more than three times after update the views on one of the smalls I get an OutOfMemory Exception. I understand that this caused by the bitmans and for that reason I set the Universal Image Loader to cache the images on the disk and not on memory. Also when someone press on one of the smalls I clear both memort and disc cache. But still I got the exception. Any ideas how to handle it?

**Universal Image Loader Code**

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            //.cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(_activity.getApplicationContext()).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
```

**Activity Style Image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
try using 

    profile_options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.placeholder) 
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .considerExifParams(true)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .build();
```

or download the latest version of universal lmage loader

Comment: I have the latest already. I tried your code and I can say from MAT that it really consumes very few memory. Wow. Why this happening? I mean I just changed to show on image in case of failing or loading... why is takes less memory?

Comment: Actually I tried some more tests and the problem still exists. I get the exception.

Comment: @user3907002: it's probably because of .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)